# How can I change popover placement in angular js depending screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popover

Here is my Code in AngularJs Application.

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 myMoodTitle">
    <span class="headText">My Mood</span>
    <a id="openMyMoodMsgBox" class="fa fa-question-circle     tooltipInfo" uib-popover-template="'chatMySettingsMoodPopover.html'" popover-class="chat-mysettings-mymood" ng-click="open('1')" popover-is-open="isOpen1"></a>
</div>
```

Above code,  I don't use `popover-placement` tag. I want to change this when screen resolution will be less than **768px** it will be shown `popover-placement` is bottom.
I am trying below this way but it doesn't work:

```
var $iW = $(window).innerWidth();
if ($iW < 768){
    $('.chat-mysettings-mymood').popover({placement: 'bottom'});
}
else{
    $('.chat-mysettings-mymood').popover({placement: 'right'});
};
```

Here, `chat-mysettings-mymood` is popover class name. I am trying to solve this problem but I am failed and this code does not work.

When I use `popover-placement="right"` tag beside `popover-class` tag it works but How can I control it depending my screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

use angular expression for *popover-placement*:

```
<a id="openMyMoodMsgBox" 
   class="fa fa-question-circle tooltipInfo" 
   uib-popover-template="'chatMySettingsMoodPopover.html'" 
   popover-placement="{{ placement }}" 
   popover-class="chat-mysettings-mymood" 
   ng-click="open('1')" 
   popover-is-open="isOpen1"></a>
```

JS file:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.isOpen1 = true;

  updatePlacement();

  $(window).on('resize', updatePlacement);

  function updatePlacement () {
    $timeout(function () {
      console.log('W = ' + $(window).innerWidth());
      $scope.placement = $(window).innerWidth() < 768 ? 'bottom' : 'right';
    });
  }
});
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Iy9y71YUWcYD1vvykQH9?p=preview

Comment: I understood that popover placement will be dynamic...but how can I apply   in my code. Please explain with a simple example...However, thanks for reply.

Comment: I provided you a fully functional example, please see my plunker -> example.js file, placement value is calculated in the controller, once when your app is loaded and then on each window resize ( try to resize preview window in the plunker to see changees). Also open console window, I am printing current windows width with console.log() function there for convenience

Comment: I updated my answer with JS code, BTW, it is based on official bootstrap-ui demo - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover (their plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer..I have got my problem's solution.Again thanks...